# Is the pictured seedling a Sycamore or field maple?

Tags: identification, trees, bonsai, maple

I recently dug up a 3 year old self seeded specimen from my garden that I intend to bonsai after I move house. I originally thought it was a field maple ([*Acer campestre*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acer_campestre)) but am starting to suspect it may in fact be a sycamore ([*Acer pseudoplatanus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acer_pseudoplatanus)).

[image: Close up of leaves]

[image: Stem an buds]

Any help / confirmation of the species / variety would be very much appreciated, as I know sycamore can be harder to achieve leaf reduction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The leaf margins are serrated, which makes it a Sycamore. From the Wikipedia article for [*Acer pseudoplatanus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acer_pseudoplatanus):

> The leaves are opposite, large, 10 to 25 cm (4 to 10 in) long and broad, palmately 5-lobed, with pointed, coarsely serrated lobes.

[image: enter link description here]
[<sub>image source</sub>](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File%3AAcer_pseudoplatanus_leaf_Weinsberg_20070506.jpg)

And for [*A. campestre*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acer_campestre):

> The leaves are in opposite pairs, 5–16 centimetres (2.0–6.3 in) long (including the 3–9 centimetres (1.2–3.5 in) petiole) and 5–10 centimetres (2.0–3.9 in) broad, with five blunt, rounded lobes with a smooth margin.

[image: enter link description here]
[<sub>image source</sub>](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File%3AAcer_campestre_dig._Sariano_06-05-2006.jpg)

Comment: I was beginning to suspect that this was the case. Thanks for the confirmation. It helps to get an outside assessment when you've been swinging back and forth in your identification for so long. Started to get blind to all of the information I was reading.